# Find a matrix $S$ to convert the matrix $A$ to a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, change-of-basis

Given the matrix 
$$\begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
  a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

and $p(T) := T^n - a_{n-1}T^{n-1} - \cdots - a_0$

If we know that $p(T)$ has exactly $n$ roots $(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$ .

So how would I find a basis change matrix $S$ so that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix?

We proved in a previous question that if a $\lambda$ is a root of $p(T) \implies (1, \lambda, \cdots, \lambda^{n-1}) $ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue  $\lambda$, but I don't know if this helps.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Comment: If you have $n$ eigenvectors, then you have the columns of your matrix $S$.  If $p$ doesn't have $n$ distinct roots, then the matrix fails to be diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you guys :)